# HTML5 AppCache: Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (6)

Tags: html, apache, caching

I experience the following error in the chrome console when the browser attempts to cache from one of our servers.  The application is indeed supposed to use the appcache.

```
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (6)
```

Where it fails in the order of things varies--it's always after the 'checking for update' event, and sometimes during the 'downloading' event of the appCache.

On another one of our servers, I observed that the download commonly works.  A coworkers laptop however, will, periodically fail with the same error, even if from the 'more working server'.  We decided to compare our dev server's Apache confs.  They had diverged some.  He put my 'more-working' conf onto his server, and heyo!, the cache successfully downloaded for the first time off his server.  Still not consistently.

I've included the diff here between our apaches here: [Apache Conf Diff](http://codepad.org/TAxpCVX7) (More-working-ish on the left, more-broken-ish on the right).  It seems to possibly have something to do with the Expirations directives based on fiddling?

We run our servers with:

Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Aug 31 2011 20:18:21

There is no information from what I've found on this error out there.  Would certainly appreciate some advice!

Comment: My existing best guess is that is it correlated to invalid SSL certs.  We never receive this error on our production server where the certs are valid--only in dev where we have invalid certs.